# How to easily Git commit in Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I just upgraded to Eclipse Neon from Mars. Earlier I could just select "Commit" from the "Team" menu, and the dialog would provide checkboxes for the files I wanted to stage. I could easily hit "select all" and all files would be staged. In fact, the files already in the repository would already be checked, if I remember correctly.

Now Eclipse Neon doesn't pop up a dialog, but shows a "Git Staging" view tab. The modified files are listed as "Unstaged Changes". Yes, I'm familiar with the Git workflow, but this seems a step backwards for the Eclipse UI. How do I "stage" the file? Do I have to select them and drag-and-drop them to "Staged Changes"? Do I have to right click on them and add them to the Index?

Whatever happens, it won't let me just hit the "Commit" button---it will complain that there are no unstaged files. Am I missing some way to commit that was as easy as it was in Eclipse Mars, with auto-staging of files or at least a "stage all" button?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the time being I'm disabling the Staging View in Windows > Preferences> Team > Git > Committing, opting to use the old-fashioned Commit Dialog (the one from Eclipse Mars) instead. I don't have time to muck around with extra listbox selections, mouse clicks, and context menu selections just to commit my code.

I hope someone else comes up with a better answer. The Git Staging View was interesting... but not if it slows me down.

Comment: To be honest, I'd just use the Git Bash to do this. It's far easier and gives you greater control over your source rather than relying on the IDE to manage it for you.

Comment: Maven on the command-line gives me more control than an IDE as well---yet for normal, day-to-day work I want to use the IDE for simple building, and not have my IDE get in the way. I shouldn't be _forced_ to use Maven or Git on the command line, I think.

Comment: You're not forced to. It is simply, generally speaking, going to be far more more efficient and flexible to do so. Let the IDE do what it does best: edit code. And let your source control do its thing separately. Just my opinion. I have found too many times in the past that IDE interference with source control has negative consequences. Using the IDE to build and debug is required. Managing source control simply isn't. Each to their own though :D

Comment: "Let the IDE do what it does best: edit code." Ah, I think what you're referring to is called an "editor". I'm referring to that thing called an Integrated Development Environment, otherwise known as an IDE, which purports to **integrate** various tools into one **environment** to help with **development**. I would agree with you that a plain editor shouldn't have to deal with this. An IDE on the other hand... well, that's what it was made to do. :)

Comment: No, I'm not referring to an editor at all. I think IDEs are best at editing code, building code and generally dealing with development, debugging and testing requirements, but source control and subsequent deployment is best dealt with separately IMO. Dev is one thing. Source/version control of source/application/suites another. Final deployment yet another concern. I prefer to keep tight control of that outside of my development environment and keep the IDE for what it does best (IMO): development. Don't want my IDE adding files to source control. Like I said, each to their own though :D

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion (as the answer). I also do amends sometimes, which is easy in the commit dialog and not at all possible in the staging view.

Comment: Me three. Jumping back to the command line is like getting into a horse and buggy to drive cross-country.

Comment: I have to agree Garret!  I'm not sure what the new Staging view adds for me other than wasted time dragging and dropping.

Comment: I agree with @GarretWilson and disabled the staging view. For most day-to-day work the UI is better for me, and I jump to the terminal when I need the additional control that it offers. The GUI simplifies work (e.g. checking final diffs) for 90% of use-cases, while the power of command-line is still available.

Answer (score 4):

Select **YourProject --> Team --> Commit...**, A Git Staging console will open.

Now follow below steps for Commit or Commit and Push changes...

1. There are **two ways** to add files in Staged Changes:

   - **drag and drop** the corresponding tree node to the staged changes pane.
     [image]

     - click "**Add to Git Index**" from the context menu.
       [image]
2. Enter the **commit message**.
   [image]
3. Click "**Commit**" or "**Commit & Push**"

Comment: So there is no way to stage *all* the files in a single operation? One has to tediously stage them one by one?

Comment: Hi, @digitig just do Ctrl+A for SELECT ALL the files on Unstaged changes pane and "drag and drop" them to the Staged changes pane OR right click and "Add to Git Index" from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

There is a default option in Preferences>Git>Commiting : "Automatically stage selected ressources on commit". If this option is checked, all modified files - but with a previous version commited - will be staged automatically as you commit.

So this is only when you're adding completely new files to the project that you have to stage them. This is the same with the old dialog where you have to select new files, while the modified files are already selected.

Another tip to speed up the commit process is that :

1) The focus is already in the commit message box.

2) You can hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to commit when you've finished the message.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that creating a local directory on your computer might be a useful idea.  Then create a simple text file, put it in that local directory and do 
a Commit and push to your personal git repo.