# get rid of git unstaged changes record

Tags: git

OK So Im extremely new to `Git` so this question might be fairly easy.

So I am using the git program in eclipse and `when i hit team commit` it seems to work well for everything but this:

[image]

I don't really know how to get rid of this? How do i commit this into my project? **It's really annoying because i want it to have no files unsaved and i cant get this composer package to commit**

what do i do?

Comment: You need to stage the file. Probably by dragging it or double-clicking it or something. Then you can commit it.

Answer (score 2):

As described in "[How to easily Git commit in Eclipse Neon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920593/6309)", you can add this change to the index (aka stage it) either:

- with a drag and drop
- with a right click, and selecting the menu entry "`Add to Index`"

See also [Egit User Guide "Track Changes"](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Track_Changes):

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/d/d8/Egit-3.1-StagingViewMarkResolved.png]

But: if you don't want that change at all (meaning you want to get rid of the local change, instead of staging it/committing it), then you would need to [checkout the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29517719/6309) (that would reset its content to the index content  value)
Right click on the file/directory that you want, then select `Replace With -> HEAD version`.