# How to perform a git push automatically after committing in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Is it possible to automatically git push when I make a commit in Visual Studio 2022? I see the Commit All button by default, and I don't want to have to click the arrow beside it every time that I want to commit & push at the same time, which is the action I always do when I commit.

Visual Studio Code has a [nice setting for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47962330/736568), but I didn't see a similar settings to configure it in Visual Studio.

Comment: I do not think you will find stuff like that anywhere out-of-the-box because one of the tenets of DVCS is to be able to keep your stuff private. If it's such a pain for you, you might want to develop a git alias (or a plugin/extension.... those are also fancy) or a full-blown script that does commit/push in a single action.... considering how often I do  `git commit --amend` after committing, I wonder if this is a good idea overall but.....

Comment: @eftshift0 [Eclipse offers dedicated Commit and push button out of box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920593/7860670) Very convenient

Comment: @eftshift0 I review the diff of each file before I commit, and that helps me to avoid having to amend. Vsc and vs both have a nice looking diff built-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a keyboard shortcut to perform the commit and push instead of just commit.

Go to Tools → Options → Environment → Keyboard and optionally search the word "commit".  Find the `Team.Git.CommitAndPush` shortcut and set it to what you wish.  In this case, I remapped `Team.Git.Commit` (normally <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to `Team.Git.CommitAndPush`. When assigning the shortcut, be sure to select "Git" for the "use new shortcut in" drop down.

[image: keyboard shortcut to set commit and push]

After changing this, you can see that the drop down option now has the shortcut too:

[image: commit and push drop down option with shortcut keys listed]